# I'm testing an webpage in java selenium and having an error Element could not be scrolled into view

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium testing. And i am testing out an order option in a online store but I keep running in a problem "Element  could not be scrolled into view". Selenium can find the button but when try to click on it the error appears. In search of a solution, I have tried to search for the button by class name, id, and XPath to no luck. I have also tried using javascript to scroll it into the view also to no luck. Can anyone help me out? The problem is located at the end of the code inline `WebElement submit = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='create_order_btn']")); System.out.println("Order button found");`

```
package com.Selenium_for_intellij;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\selenium\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver obj = new FirefoxDriver();
        obj.manage().window().maximize();
        obj.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        obj.get("https://fitnesaveikals.lv");
        System.out.println("Succesfull navigation to https://fitnesaveikals.lv");
        
        obj.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nav\"]/div/ul/div/li[1]/a")).click();
        System.out.println("Tag found for akcijas peces");
        
        obj.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/h4/a")).click();
        System.out.println("First product selected");
        
        obj.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/form/button")).click();
        System.out.println("1st item added to cart");
        
        obj.findElement(By.className("menu__link--cart")).click();
        System.out.println("Clicked on a button to open cart");
        
        obj.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/section[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/a[2]")).click();
        obj.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/button[2]")).click();
        
        WebElement reg_name = obj.findElement(By.id("reg_name"));
        System.out.println("Name iput found");
        reg_name.sendKeys("Arturs");
        System.out.println("Name written");
        
        WebElement reg_emai = obj.findElement(By.id("reg_email"));
        System.out.println("Email input feild is found");
        reg_emai.sendKeys("art@cunami.lv");
        System.out.println("Email has been entered");
        
        WebElement reg_sname = obj.findElement(By.id("reg_sname"));
        System.out.println("Surname input feild is found");
        reg_sname.sendKeys("Rasnacis");
        System.out.println("Surname has been entered");
        
        WebElement reg_tel = obj.findElement(By.id("reg_tel"));
        System.out.println("Tel input feild is found");
        reg_tel.sendKeys("23543568");
        System.out.println("Tel has been entered");
        
        obj.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/label")).click();
        System.out.println("Store pickup selected");
        
        obj.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[10]/div/div/div/label")).click();
        System.out.println("Terms accepted");

        WebElement submit = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='create_order_btn']"));
        System.out.println("Order button found");
        
        submit.click(); //now it clicks on element
        System.out.println("Order submited");

        obj.close();
```

Comment: its a good practice to write relative xpaths rather than absolute xpaths

Answer (score 0):

You need to scroll to let Selenium view the button :

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 500)")
```

and then click on the button :

```
WebElement submit = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='create_order_btn']"));
submit.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)obj;
WebElement submit = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='create_order_btn']"));

js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)",submit);
submit.click();
```